# How to find the largest repeating substring given character in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given some string say 'aabaaab', how would I go about finding the largest substring of a. So it should return 'aaa'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def sub_string(s):


   best_run = 0
   current_run = 0

   for char in s:
      if char == 'a'
          current_run += 1
      else:
        current_letter = char

   return(best_run)
```

I have something like the one above. Not sure where I can fix it up.

Comment: You declare `best_run` but you never use it. Might have something to do with that

Comment: Now, that's not valid Python because of the indentation

Comment: Still not valid Python due to indentation. Do you use an IDE for coding or is it just a text editor? Do youself a favor and use an IDE.

Comment: Now your function always returns 0, because best_run is never changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the most efficient, but a straightforward solution:

```
word = "aasfgaaassaasdsddaaaaaafff"

substr_count = 0
substr_counts = []
character = "f"
for i, letter in enumerate(word):
    if (letter == character):
        substr_count += 1
    else:
        substr_counts.append(substr_count)
        substr_count = 0
    if (i == len(word) - 1):
        substr_counts.append(substr_count)

print(max(substr_counts))
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want a short method using standard python tools (and avoid writing loops to reconstruct the string as you iterate), you can use regex to split the string by any non-`a` characters than get the `max()` according to `len`:

```
import re

test_string = 'aabaaab'
split_string_list = re.split( '[^a]', test_string )
longest_string_subset = max( split_string_list, key=len )
print( longest_string_subset )
```

The `re` library is for regex, the `'[^a]'` is a regex statement for any non-`a` character. Basically, the `'aabaaab'` is being split into a list according to any matches on the regex statement, so that it becomes `[ 'aa' 'aaa' '' ]`. Then, the `max()` statement looks for the longest string based on `len` (aka length).

You can read more about functions like `re.split()` in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: This is perfect. Could you explain the re.split statement?

Comment: OP can't even implement `if` and `for` in Python and you introduce him to Regex? Not a good idea